# Add as Link Community.CsharpSqlite

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, visual-studio-express

I can go into `Community.CsharpSqlite` folder click the `Community.CsharpSqlite.csproj` and it will create a `Community.CsharpSqlite.dll` in either Release or Debug folder.

I attempted to do **Add as Link** to combine the project with my main project to avoid generating the .dll file.

But the project that makes the .dll file doesn't compile when I add it into my main project has over 240 errors because it has C code in it. Like

> The type or namespace name 'typedef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and so on it doesn't have any issues compiling as a standalone library. How do I link it up?

**Edit:** It managed to work after I copy pasted the Conditional compilation symbols: from Community.CsharpSqlite project to my main project

`DEBUG;SQLITE_DEBUG TRUE WIN32 _MSC_VER NO_TCL SQLITE_ASCII SQLITE_DISABLE_LFS SQLITE_HAS_CODEC SQLITE_MEM_POOL SQLITE_MUTEX_W32 SQLITE_THREADSAFE SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION SQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED SQLITE_OMIT_GET_TABLE SQLITE_OMIT_INCRBLOB SQLITE_OMIT_LOOKASIDE SQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE SQLITE_OMIT_UTF16 SQLITE_OMIT_WAL SQLITE_OS_WIN SQLITE_SYSTEM_MALLOC  VDBE_PROFILE_OFF`

As well as Suppressed these warnings
`0168 ; 0169; 0414; 0618; 0649`

Is that the only way of doing this? messing with main project's build information?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It managed to work after I copy pasted the `Conditional compilation symbols`: from `Community.CsharpSqlite` project to my main project

`DEBUG;SQLITE_DEBUG TRUE WIN32 _MSC_VER NO_TCL SQLITE_ASCII SQLITE_DISABLE_LFS SQLITE_HAS_CODEC SQLITE_MEM_POOL SQLITE_MUTEX_W32 SQLITE_THREADSAFE SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION SQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED SQLITE_OMIT_GET_TABLE SQLITE_OMIT_INCRBLOB SQLITE_OMIT_LOOKASIDE SQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE SQLITE_OMIT_UTF16 SQLITE_OMIT_WAL SQLITE_OS_WIN SQLITE_SYSTEM_MALLOC VDBE_PROFILE_OFF`

`As well as Suppressed these warnings`0168 ; 0169; 0414; 0618; 0649`

Now it works.